# Validate Form Against a Text File

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a simple form input box on my site that the user enters a 4 digit code into & submits.  I need that code to match a list of codes in a text file.  If not, it just returns an error.  If so, it would execute another function.  Using PHP.

I'm struggling on how to compare against that text file, seems simple to me...

I appreciate all of your help, learned SOOO much from SO.

Ian

Comment: Show us your PHP and a sample of your text file.

Comment: If you convert the text file into an array using phps explode() function, then compare the array against the input is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't provided a sample of your file or PHP code, am submitting the following:

Considering `data.txt` contains and with no commas from a `.csv` file, this will work.

```
1111
1112
1113
```

PHP

```
<?php
$search = "1111";
$file = "data.txt";

    if (preg_match('/^' . $search . '$/m', file_get_contents($file))) {
        echo "$file DOES contains $search\n";

    } else {
        echo "$file does NOT contain $search\n";
    }
```

This is another method which will work with or without a comma-seperated file:

```
1111,
1112,
1113,
```

PHP

```
<?php

$search = "1111";
$file = fopen("data.txt", "r") or die("Cannot open file!\n"); 
while ($line = fgets($file, 1024)) { 

//if (preg_match("/\b1111\b/i", $line)) { 

if (preg_match("/\b$search\b/i", $line)) { 

        echo "<b>Found match: " . $line . "</b>";
    } else { 
        echo "No match: " . $line; 
    } 
} 
fclose($file);
```